# View Configuration File Changes With RPM or Yum

Tags: yum, diff, rpm

How do I view the changes made to package configuration files (installed using rpm/yum)?

I created a FreeRadius server that does MAC Authentication, and I just want to get the lines that I have modified that are different than the default installation. Do I have to install the RPM into a chroot, or is there a yum or rpm command that can be used to find this information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am afraid `rpm -V` + `rpmpeek` is the best you'll get.

If you have your rpms cached, you could try something like:

```
for RPM in $RPMS; do
    for FILE in `rpm -V $RPM | sed -e 's+^[^/]*++'` | grep '^/etc/'; do
        rpmpeek $RPM diff $FILE .$FILE
    done
done
```

I am looking for something similar and so far have not found anything better...

Comment: Well, this is a bit old, and I'm not worried about this anymore. I'll assume your answer is correct, thanks for the help.

Comment: 2016 and i have the same question.  @Martian, could you write a yum plugin to do this?

Comment: How do I "cache" an rpm?

Comment: keepcache in yum.conf (or dnf.conf). the packages are kept in /var/cache/yum (or dnf). Alternatively one can use etckeeper to keep track of all config changes.